# Is it possible to clear an input type="color" field which is not not required?

Tags: html, forms

If I declare the following input field:

```
<input type="color" name="col1" value="#ff0000">
```

In Chrome 41 and Firefox 36, there doesn't seem to be any way to clearing the field before I submit the form. Given the I have not set the required attribute on the field, is this a mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: I have the exact same need: I have a color field which is optional (not required) and when is not set the application will have a default. However there is no easy way to detect if the user has entered a color or not. I think that the color input has a really bad design: it should have allowed blank values!

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't change its value to "transparent", and there is no `NULL` in CSS.

Why do you need to "clear" it though? If Javascript is supported in your application, you could listen to the `change` event and change another input (ex: `type="hidden"`) to specify that the user picked a color.

Comment: The use case is to have optional branding configuration. The application supports defaults, so if the value isn't specified then we don't generate the extra CSS to override the default. It's not that I'm trying to express transparent, more that I want an unset value.